# Limiting API Calls in Ruby Via Refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I have a view in ruby with this code:

```
<%= f.select(:shipping_type, options_for_select(ship_options)) %>
```

This is calling for shipping options from a helper method that looks like this:

```
def ship_options
    ship_options = {}
    if ship_options.count != 4
        @order_preview.fedex_rates.each do |k, v|
            if k.service_name == "FedEx Ground Home Delivery" || k.service_name == "FedEx 2 Day" || k.service_name == "FedEx Standard Overnight"
                ship_options["#{k.service_name}"] = "#{number_to_currency(k.price.to_f / 100)}"
            end
        end
        @order_preview.usps_rates.each do |k, v|
            if k.service_name == "USPS Priority Mail 1-Day"
                ship_options["#{k.service_name}"] = "#{number_to_currency(k.price.to_f / 100)}"
            end
        end
        ship_options.map { |k,v| ["#{k} - #{v}","#{k} - #{v}" ] }
    end    
    raise
end
```

The problem with this code is that every time a user views the page, it's calling for ship_options.  Since the method here declares the hash as empty to start with, I'm limited from using a logical counter

```
if ship_options.count != 4
```

because it restarts it to 0 every time the option is called and then needs to call the API again.  How could I refactor my code to be able to do what I want (ie not reinstantiate an empty hash in the beginning  of the method and use the above logic to determine whether or not I need to call the API

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When the user hits the view for the first time, I would like the API to get called so the shipping methods and prices populate, but if they refresh the page -- it does not call it again

Comment: where are you planning to keep the cached result?

Comment: That is in part what I am asking - the helper?

Comment: Is it a global cache? per order cache? how often does it change...?

Comment: I would like it to be per order.  As of now it calls the API every time the view is loaded - I'm not sure how often it would change.  I think it would be okay to cache once per session

Comment: then add it to the @order model

Comment: the entire hash saved to db? haven't done that before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54695/discussion-between-uri-agassi-and-peege151).

Comment: If you have a cache enabled (such as memcached) you could cache the result of ship_option using an order id as key...